# Angular ngOptions Slice or ellipse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slice

I've got some really long sentences showing in ngOptions which i am populating from an api.. how can i slice em up so i end up with something like ( red... or blue...) with dots at the end of word..., ummm may be i should try creating a filter where i should get the length of str and than slice it depending how many characters i want..any help be appreciated.

```
$scope.colors = [
  {name:'blacksomerandomwords', shade:'dark'},
  {name:'whitesomerandomwords', shade:'light', notAnOption: true},
  {name:'redsomerandomwords', shade:'dark'},
  {name:'bluesomerandomwords', shade:'dark', notAnOption: true},
  {name:'yellowsomerandomwords', shade:'light', notAnOption: false}
]; 
<select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name for color in colors"></select>
```

Comment: Do you want to cut only the selected option or dropdown menu as well?

Comment: dropdown as well otherwise the dropdown is too wide..can control it with setting width or overflow hidden but rather looking for solution using javascript slice, Thanks

Comment: I guess angular filters are your best option. Especially when you consider cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
yourApp.filter('short', function() { 
  // pass in collection, property to shorten and max length
  return function(values, property, length) {
    angular.forEach(values, function(value) { 
      value[property] = value[property].length <= length ? 
                        value[property] : 
                        value[property].substr(0, length) + '...';  
    });
    return values;
  };
});

<select ng-model="myColor" 
        ng-options="color.name for color in colors | short:'name':6">
</select>
```

Related plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/Mvky0H

Comment: Hi Mikko, i tried your solution but i am getting => Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Thanks ver much Mikko, it worked..sorry i was using  => short:'name':6 .....but in my actual app it is full_address, so it should been short:'full_address':6  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS style `text-overflow:ellipsis` to populate the effect: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp. As long as you limit the width of your options wrapper element.

Comment: Thanks Cai, i was more looking for a angular filter. but thanks for your help any way...i did tried text-overflow:ellipsis but for some reason it didn't work..i tried adding a class with the properties you mentioned on select, as well on options..but no luck yet...